# What happens if I short the motherboard's internal front audio/USB headers?

Tags: usb, audio, motherboard, computer-building, soldering

My front panel audio stopped working, so I removed the panel PCB replaced the 3.5mm audio jack with a new one.

I soldered it myself, and it does not look pretty. So before I attach it to my motherboard, I would like to know if it is OK to (accidentally) short the motherboard's front panel audio or USB headers.

#### Motherboard Audio Header:

[image: Motherboard Audio Header]

#### Replacement Audio Jack

[image: Replacement Audio Jack]

Comment: Do you have a pic of your soldering job? I know you might be embarrassed but the pics you have posted only show the bookends to the issue, and not the core issue.

Comment: I'm assuming that I shorted nearby pins together while soldering them.

Comment: No; It isn’t ok to short the pins

Comment: *"I shorted nearby pins together while soldering them"* -- Since you shouldn't be soldering a powered board,  there is no issue with shorting pins (temporarily).

Answer (score 1):

That really depends which pins. If you touched the line-level pins or `NC` (not connected), no issue. If you touched the +5V lines to something else, potentially... depending on what you shorted them to. Use the below image as a guide.

[image]

The outcome also very much depends on whether the machine was powered on at the time of the short.

Best case, you shorted 2 line-level pins which is not an issue. Worst case, you put 5V to ground, but it should dissipate through he ground wires into the PSU. There are some other possible outcomes listed [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36320/what-happens-if-we-connect-gnd-and-5v).

Comment: So it is NOT OK to short motherboard's audio header pins.

Comment: *"Worst case, you put 5V to ground, but it should dissipate through he ground wires into the PSU."* -- You make this case seem inconsequential. The +5V supply blows its fuse if not worse.

Comment: @sawdust that's why I linked the other thread.

Comment: @Jack it really depends on what you shorted, as per my answer.